# How to trace login auth in php laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I have this log-out code below working fine. But upon log-out I can't log-in anymore it keeps reloading in log-in just like refreshing the page. Is there a way to trace or track what is going on in the code of log-in?. Or put a breakpoint in VS-Code?.

**Log-out**

```
  <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
        <i class="fa fa-sign-out-alt nav-icon"></i>
            <p>{{ __('Logout') }} </p>
          </a>
          <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" class="d-none">
            @csrf
          </form>
        </li>
```

But when I register and successfully registered it redirects me to my homepage. And then click the log-out causes me again the problem.

> Edit

Upon click the log-out here is my network tab.
[image]

Upon exploring I ended up here in `RedirectIfAuthenticated`. I have notice that upon log-in the `$guards` is empty that is why I can't log-in.

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
{
    $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

    foreach ($guards as $guard) {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

But When I add this code in my `Http > Controllers > Auth > LoginController > __construct()`

```
     if (Auth::attempt(array('username' => 'Apples', 'password' => '123456'))) {
          return Redirect::intended('dashboard');
     }
```

It redirects me to my homepage fine. But I don't want this approach because it's static.

> Note : I am using Laravel 8

Comment: Have you checked console/network tab? Other hand a tag has href and onclick event as well.

Comment: @Beller upon creating the auth ui. I didn't edit anything to the HTML. It's still the same. And no error in console.

Comment: Is logout post request appear on network tab?

Comment: @Beller yes upon clicking the log-out I see a logout

Comment: Get or post? Or both?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228882/discussion-between-beller-and-kira).